# `BrowserRouter` is creating `.PropTypes is undefined` Error in ReactJS.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use the `react-router-dom` for the first time. I am having an error `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__.PropTypes is undefined`. My code looks like as given below. I cannot understand what am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

//COMPONENTS
import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer';
import Home from './home'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Header />
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: which version of React Router ?

Comment: I am using `v4.0.0`.

Comment: `PropTypes` errors can often relate to React versions, between v15 and v16. Ensure you're using the right version of `react` for the version of `react-router` you're using (check the module's documentation and compatibilities, check for dependency issues when installing the modules, etc.)

Comment: Thank you @Jayce444. It is working now.

Comment: I am having the same issue. How can this be dealt with?